# SCSS works without SASS-loader in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, sass-loader

This is something weird that I am unable to figure out.
I did not install sass-loader from Vue, nor did I configure webpack for SCSS, but it still works fine when I use

```html
<style lang='scss'>....some SCSS code here....</style>
```

inside my Vue component.

Comment: Depending on how you installed webpack, this loader may have been preconfigured ( for example: Vue-CLI, rails webpacker gem). What is the question?

Comment: **(vue init webpack-simple name-of-the-project)**         I did it this way. From the documentation I read that sass-loader and node-sass are needed to be installed and sass-loader needs to be configured in webpack.config.js. My question is, how does it still work without me installing the loader to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research: vue init is deprecated syntax for [Vue-CLI 2.x](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v2) that used to clone templates into your new project folder. One of these templates is the [webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) which you defined in your command.

In the [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js) for this template, you can see that sass-loader is preconfigured.

---

Since Vue-CLI 3.0 and up, the command used to generate a new app is [`vue create`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create).